# Importing XML to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I am wondering how I can insert an XML file into a SQL Server DB. Below is the XML I have but I am unsure how to do this in a way that will scale. My thought is a Insert Into Select statement but I do not know if that is going to work as the data increases. Thank you in advance!

```
<Records>
    <Record>
        <ID SpecNum="5069580" IssueNum="001" SpecStatus="Pre-Approved">
            <NutritionDetails>
                <NutrientFacts>
                    <NutrientNameId>ENERC_KCAL</NutrientNameId>
                    <NutrientName>ENERC_KCAL</NutrientName>  
                    <NutrientPer100gUnrounded>1.91</NutrientPer100gUnrounded>
                    <NutrientPer100gRounded>191</NutrientPer100gRounded>
                </NutrientFacts>
            </NutritionDetails>
        </ID>
    </Record>
</Records>
```

Comment: Well, which bits and pieces of your XML do you want to extract and insert into which columns of what table??

Comment: Are those thousands of records in a single row of a database table, or is it thousands of rows with one or two elements each?

Comment: Hi @marc_s, preferably everything in between the "record" tags. In theory there can be thousands of records in my case and that is where I am looking for a way to handle these requests.

Comment: The latter of what you stated. Think of SpecNum to be unique for each row. So if a thousand "records" came in then it should be a thousand rows with all the subsequent details as values/columns.

Comment: OK, but there would be many `<Record>` elements - right? But each "record" then has just one `<ID>` and `<NutritionDetails>` tag inside?

Comment: Yes that is correct. Sorry for confusion on last comment, there can be thousands of "Record" inside of the "Records" tags. I will change the naming conventions down the road.

Comment: OK - another question - the XML is invalid, as shown - the `<ID>` tag isn't closed. Is that a *self-closing" tag, or does it "wrap around" the `<NutritionDEtails> ` tag ?? (and `<NutrientFacts>` also isn't closed.....)

Comment: Yes my apologies all of the nutrition details are inside of the ID tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you've successfully created a proper, valid XML - you should be able to use this T-SQL code to grab the details:

```
SELECT
    -- get the attributes from the <ID> node
    IDSpecNum = XC.value('(ID/@SpecNum)[1]', 'int'),
    IDIsseNum = XC.value('(ID/@IssueNum)[1]', 'int'),
    IDSpecStatus = XC.value('(ID/@SpecStatus)[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
    -- get the element values from the children of the <NutrientFacts> node
    NutrientNameId = NUT.value('(NutrientNameId)[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
    NutrientName = NUT.value('(NutrientName)[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
    NutrientPer100gUnrounded = NUT.value('(NutrientPer100gUnrounded)[1]', 'decimal(20,4)'),
    NutrientPer100gRounded = NUT.value('(NutrientPer100gRounded)[1]', 'decimal(20,4)')
FROM
    dbo.YourTable
CROSS APPLY
    -- get one XML fragment per <Record>
    XmlData.nodes('/Records/Record') AS XT(XC)
CROSS APPLY
    -- get one XML fragment per <NutrientFacts> inside
    XC.nodes('ID/NutritionDetails/NutrientFacts') AS XT2(NUT)
```

The first `CROSS APPLY` basically get an "inline pseudo table" with one XML fragment for each `<Record>` node in your XML in the `XmlData` column of your table (this is just an **assumption** on my part - adapt to your reality!). These XML fragments are referenced as "pseudo-table" `XT` with a single column `XC`.

With that `XC` column's XML fragment, you can "reach in" and grab the attribute values from the `<ID>` node in the `<Record>` - that's the first three values.

Then, based on the `XT` pseudo table, I apply another `CROSS APPLY` to get all the `<NutrientFacts>` nodes inside `<ID> / <NutritionDetails>` - those are referenced as pseudo-table `XT2` with column `NUT`, which again holds an XML fragment for each `<NutrientFacts>` node; I reach into that XML node and extract the values from the sub-elements of that node - those are the four additional values that are shown in the select.

Now that you have a `SELECT` that returns all the values - you can easily get those bits you need and use them in a `INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable(list-of-columns) SELECT list-of-columns :......` scenario. Enjoy!

**UPDATE:** to import an XML file from disk (local disk on your **SQL Server** machine's file system) into your table - use something like this:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable(XmlData)
    SELECT 
        CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn) AS BulkColumn
    FROM 
        OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\temp\records.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x;
```

Again: adapt to your needs - I don't know if you want to insert additional information into `dbo.YourTable` - and I don't even know your table name; you can load one XML at a time from disk

Comment: Thank you for quick response marc_s. To clarify will this be able to find an XML file in directory and then insert it into a table in my database? I might be missing it from your answer above and apologize if I am.

Comment: @Gutzy: no, this assumes your XML is **already** in `dbo.YourTable`, in a `XmlData` column of datatype `XML` .....

Comment: @marc-s this is awesome and thank you for the in depth explanation with your code? Hate to bother you with this question but how would I get the initial XML file into a table? I understand what you provided but I need to get to that point.

Comment: @Gutzy: added an addendum to my response

Comment: thank you for your help this is what I was looking for!

Comment: Hi @marc_s, on your update I am unable to import all of my data into my table. Do I need multiple CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn) AS BulkColumn lines? I have tried a few different ways but keep getting errors with this method.

Comment: @Gutzy: I don't think this supports multiple files - you need to import one by one

Comment: @Gutzy: you should put that into a new question and see who can help with that

Comment: that is fine but what I mean is based on the code you had provided it does not work. Should there be something different in mine other than (XmlData)?

Comment: @Gutzy: don't use `SELECT *` - use `SELECT BulkColumn ....` as I had shown

Comment: before I played around with any of the code you provided, it didn't work successfully. The error I receive when executing is: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 20
Invalid column name 'XmlData'.